# How does a chess club become recognized by FIDE?

Tags: fide, clubs

First question [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7969/opening-a-chess-club), I split it into 2 questions

What would it take for the club to be recognized by FIDE? At first the club would be a place to have fun, but later on, I would like that the club become recognized  by FIDE, I would like to give the members FIDE ratings and to participate in local and international events.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What would it take for the club to be recognized by FIDE?

FIDE does not recognize chess clubs (except perhaps maybe for club world cup competitions?). Depending on your country, your national chess federation (NCF) will likely need to recognize your club to allow you to participate in national team tournaments.

> I would like to give the members FIDE ratings

FIDE gives the ratings to players who have played in a tournament that has been registered as a FIDE-rated tournament. If you want to organize such a tournament, you should discuss with your NCF.

> and to participate in local and international events.

Your NCF may require each player to belong to a club recognized by the NCF before participating in tournaments rated by NCF. In international events, there is no requirement by FIDE to belong to a national club, but each player needs to register with FIDE via the NCF before entering the competition (since July 2014; before that registration was possible after the tournament).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately JiK is just plain wrong!  FIDE accredited clubs (called FIDE academies) are all over the world.  According to FIDE representatives in the FIDE Trainers' Commission they are looking to rapidly expand to 500 approved FIDE Clubs worldwide by 2017.  Currently there are 33.  You need to pay for this AND have approval from your National Chess Federation.  Some details with this will be changing as it seems that most national chess federations don't like some of the power that these academies have.  For more information you can visit : http://trainers.fide.com/fide-academies.html for more.  The serious question is it worth the fee!  When I inquired in October 2014 it was 500 euro for the first year and 200 (or 300??) every year after.  This is not ideal for a small club, but it seems you wouldn't want it right away!  Hope that helps!
I should also mention that your club name stays the same, but you get to add FIDE academy to your logos, letterhead and advertisments...

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about FIDE academies! However, I don't see it mentioned anywhere that these are chess clubs and not a completely different thing. Can you give pointers to something more specific?

Comment: Perhaps you should learn English better then : Club -  1. an association dedicated to a particular interest or activity.
2.
an organization constituted to play matches in a particular sport.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive response. I think the "chess club" the OP means in the question is club by definition 2, and to me, "FIDE academy" seems like an association dedicated to teaching chess (which can be called a club by definition 1), so if I'm right, FIDE academies are not directly related to this question.

Comment: Thank you for your continued conversation. Unfortunately you are not right, as stated above!